# Root cron job can't read file from /root/

Tags: permissions, cron

I've got a cron job in root's crontab defined like this:

```
0 1 * * * /usr/local/bin/tarsnap-backup-script > /tmp/tarsnapcron.txt 2> /tmp/tarsnapcron.err
```

The script is a python script that executes `tarsnap`, which reads the key from `/root/tarsnap.key`. This key is owned by root and chmod 400.

If I run the script from the bash shell, it executes without error. However, under cron, I get a python exception printed to `tarsnapcron.err`:

```
could not change directory to "/root": Permission denied
```

What's the difference between running this script as `root` in bash, and running it from `root`'s crontab? Why can the latter not read from `/root`?

Comment: Is it a setuid script? Did you check your audit log?

Comment: What's the script ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton script doesn't call setuid. Which audit log do you mean? Script is from the puppet tarsnap module, script template is here: https://github.com/puppetmodules/puppet-module-tarsnap/blob/master/templates/tarsnap-backup.py.erb

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the solution was, to grant root group rights:

```
chmod 440 /root/backup.key
```

After that cron was able to read the file, and the backup script run flawlessly.